# UITableViewCell: subviews shadows cut off by other cells and outside of table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, shadow

I have a design with cells with a vertical spacing of 10px. I would like to set shadows around these cells (actually I apply these shadows to a subview of each of these cells), but here is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you can see the shadow is being cut off both by the other cells and by the table view header/footer.

Here is my code:

**The view controller**

```
final class SCVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShadowCell", bundle: .main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShadowCell")
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

extension SCVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShadowCell", for: indexPath) as! ShadowCell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                              size: CGSize(width: tableView.bounds.width,
                                                           height: 20)))
        headerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 16, y: 8),
                                          size: CGSize(width: headerView.frame.width - 32,
                                                       height: 34)))
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.text = "Header view"
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
}
```

**The cell**

```
final class ShadowCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView! {
        didSet {
            innerView.backgroundColor = .white
            innerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            innerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
            innerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            innerView.layer.shadowRadius = 24.0
            innerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
        }
    }
}
```

**The cell XIB**

[image]

How could I fix this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, if something is clipping, there may be two main reasons:

1. `clipsToBounds` set to `true`.
2. `backgroundColor` is not `.clear`

so to solve your problem you need to fix those for both cell and it's content view. you can do it in your xib, or in the code:

```
cell.clipsToBounds = false
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realized what was wrong by using the debug view hierarchy tool, the only part of the UI I was not clipping was the `cell.contentView`.

Comment: It works well. clipsToBounds to false on both of cell and cell.contentView is necessary.

Comment: you are perfect! When I need the same thing I hacked UITableView and drew shadows behind cells inside table directly

Answer (score 1):

My collection view clipped the shadow:

```
myCollectionView.clipsToBounds = false ✅
```